# OOP null value for date or a random date in super constructor

Tags: java, object, oop, software-design

I'm working with a class in Java that implements the functionality of a ticket:

```
public class Ticket {
    private LocalDateTime dateAndTime;
    private String departureCity;
    private String arrivalCity;

    public Ticket(LocalDateTime dateAndTime, String departureCity, String arrivalCity) {
        assert (isDateAndTimeCorrect(dateAndTime));
        assert (isRouteCorrect(departureCity, arrivalCity));
        /** ... **/
    }

    public double getPrice() { /** ... **/ }

    @Override
    public String toString() { /** ... **/ }

    public String getDepartureCity() { /** ... **/ }

    public String getArrivalCity() { /** ... **/ }

    public LocalDateTime getDateAndTime() { /** ... **/ }

    public boolean isDateAndTimeCorrect(LocalDateTime dateAndTime) {
        return dateAndTime != null && dateAndTime.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    public boolean isRouteCorrect(String departureCity, String arrivalCity) {
        return departureCity != null && arrivalCity != null && !departureCity.isEmpty() && !arrivalCity.isEmpty()
                && !departureCity.equals(arrivalCity);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is intended to represent a normal Ticket. But, now I want to add to the system a more specific type of ticket called `OpenTicket`, which allows an undetermined date and time for the ticket without modifying the original `Ticket` class. I can’t modify the `Ticket` class because I don’t own it.

According to the principles of Object Oriented Programming, which is the best alternative to proceed? Calling the Ticket constructor from a child class with a future date than `.now()`? Or calling `super(...)` with `null` value in the date attribute and somehow manage to avoid the assertion?

Comment: either way, you'll be setting a date for that ticket, which violates your requirements

Comment: @stultuske Then, how can I implement the `OpenTicket` class?

Comment: either set a date, which is not what you want, since that 'll be the exact date of your ticket, or alter the parent class

Comment: You can call the construtor with null as date and override `isDateAndTimeCorrect`, so that is accept the null value

Comment: @jens If I override the function, it will only be valid in the child class, not in the parent, causing the assertion to throw an error

Comment: @Jens that would be the solution not to touch the class Ticket, but a very counter-intuitive design if you ask me. Unless Ticket doesn't belong to you, I don't see why you shouldn't touch it - the code is text to be changed easily.

Comment: Why you don't want to touch the Ticket class? It is clear to me that a Ticket is a specialization of an OpenTicket and not vice versa. It's like you want to create an Animal class that extends Dog.

Comment: @matteo-nnz Ticket class can´t be modified because it´s not my ownership, sorry.

Comment: In this case, I don't see any other solution that setting the date at 31-12-3500 and that will be the problem of the developers born after that date (seriously speaking, an open ticket is a ticket without date, so it may make sense to say that until when it's used, the date is a date in the far future. If there wasn't that assertion "after LocalDate.now()" it would have made more sense to set it to null, but since the assertion is there and you can't modify the code, I don't see what else you can do).

Comment: what's stopping you from creating your own Ticket class?

Comment: @stultuske Ticket is intended to act as the representation of a "normal" ticket. And, the OpenTicket is considered to be a special kind of normal ticket that somehow overrides parent date constraints and leaves it undetermined. If it were up to me, I would do it the opposite, but this is what I have to implement.

Comment: @matteo-nnz Is it possible to somehow overshadow the parent date attribute to make it work?

Comment: If the assertion wasn't called in the constructor you may have overridden the method as @Jens was suggesting. But since the call is made within the Ticket constructor, even if you override it you'd still be calling the one of the parent class. Apart for doing messy stuff by reflection, I think you should really go for setting a very far date (which can be seen as "no specific date for this ticket")

Comment: As shown in the comments, the Ticket class is not flexible enough and you can't subclass it as the inheritance would the in the wrong direction. The Ticket class actually represents a specific timed ticket. Thus you can't substitute an "open" ticket for it because whatever "date" you artificially make this open ticket for, will be wrong. What you can do is, when the OpenTicket gets presented for a specific journey, then its date is modified to be the date of the journey.

Comment: @k314159 the problem with your approach (that would be a clean one for sure) is that over construction of Ticket there is a check to make sure that the given date comes after LocalDate.now(). At the same time, there's no setter for the date meaning that once the date is set, you can't change it any longer even if the field is not final. Hence, you can't really leave it unset until when the ticket is presented, hence my suggestion of setting it to a very far date.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ your suggestion would work only if a future-dated ticket was valid for today's travel. That's not the case with most tickets.

Comment: @k314159 we have no spec on how this information is used :) Of course the right response lies in how this API is actually used

Comment: Your design does not agree with my book. You will either be in conflict with the Liskov Substitution Principle or with reality. If you put a dummy date and time in your open ticket, you will be telling a lie. If you put `null`, any client expecting a `Ticket` and knowing that a `Ticket` has a date and time will be prone to null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Assuming you cannot or don’t want to throw the given, unmodifiable `Ticket` class overboard even though its design isn’t suitable for your purpose, a solution could be the facade design pattern: Define an interface that holds for all tickets, open or not. Implement it in two classes. The "normal ticket" class will internally hold a reference to an instance of the existing `Ticket` class. The "open ticket" implementation can either be written from scratch or can hold a `Ticket` too, taking well care of the design problems that there are with using a `Ticket` instance for an open ticlet.